# excitatory-inhibitory synapse ratio

Tags: neuroscience, synapses

For each inhibitory synapse, how many excitatory synapses are in the brain?
It is the same ratio along the animal kingdom or nervous system areas?

Comment: E/I synapse ratio probably isn't the most informative measure, because you leave out the release probability of synapses, the postsynaptic efficacy of a synapse, the level of presynaptic activity, the spatiotemporal correlation of inhibition and excitation, the meanings of excitation and inhibition in different parts of the animal kingdom, the temporal features of rapid neurotransmitters vs slower neuromodulators, etc etc.

Comment: I'm aware that at a dynamical level E/I balance could be very different than E/I balance at the anatomical level. For my purposes, I want to have an estimation of the E/I ratio in terms of connectivity alone.